# Error migrating truffle rinkeby [Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined]

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I'm trying to deploy/migrate contract to rinkeby network, while using command:
truffle deploy --reset --network=rinkeby

It loads the keys and afterwards throws error:

```
C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:26

var originalSendAsync = provider.sendAsync.bind(provider);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

I'm able to run truffle develop without any issues
I'm also using:

- truffle-hdwallet-provider
- zappelin-solidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue was comming from the truffle-hdwallet-provider version.

changing the ver from : 1.0.0-web3one.2
to : 0.0.6

solved the issue